# How can an operating system be installed when the installation media is missing?

Tags: installation, windows-installation, system-recovery

Often when trying to fix someone else's computer - especially consumer machines - the operating system will need to be reinstalled, but the owner will have lost or never created the installation or recovery media.

How can the system be legally restored to the original functionality?

Comment: I think this needs to be on superuser.com and voted to move it, but I will say that the media isn't important, the licence is. It's easier/cheaper to legally obtain new media than it is a new licence. You might think I'm splitting hairs but this is fundemental to solving your problem.

Comment: Surely if the machine has a license sticker on it, it's legal to reinstall that version from your own media?

Comment: Yes, but consumer machines often have special media. Often the license number on the sticker will not activate generic Windows media. Also, any pre-installed software that might have been on the machine will be lost.

Comment: The 'legally' is a tricky criterium. Without it, your problem would be solved trivially, but laws, agreements and situations can vary so greatly, a concise and conclusive answer is well beyond what one can reasonably expect in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I keep Dell install disc for XP with sp3 handy, it will install on any OEM PC without using a key, it will not activate however, when it fails to activate you will be able to change the key, punch in the key on the COA sticker that is on the PC, it should activate now. This is not an easy way, you still have to find all the drivers, and customers will complain all their OEM pre-installed software is missing.

It is the responsibility of the owner to keep up with discs and keys, not yours.

On many PCs like Dell, HP, Acer, there is a recovery partition on the hard drive that can reload the OS clean. Go to the manufacturers website for instructions.

Link for legal downloads of Windows 7 ISO images of install discs: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/04/28/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/ (I suggest you get copies of these for future use, you will still need a legal key to activate the software.)

For Windows Vista, here is a [link](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/w/microsoft_os/3317.2-3-microsoft-windows-vista-official-iso-download-links-digital-river.aspx) to a Dell community web page that describes the process to download and recreate Windows Vista (with SP1) bootable DVDs.

---

If you have activation problems with legitimate keys, here are the toll free Microsoft activation hotline numbers for the USA:

- **Windows XP:** 1(888)571-2048
- **Windows Vista:** 1(866)740-1256
- **Windows 7:** 1(888)725-1047

Comment: don't forget that you can use something like Jelly Bean or Belarc Advisor to find the OS Key, for reinstalling (if possible). +1 when I get more votes.

Comment: Just so others know, the key "keyfinders" will find is the OEM VLK key, which is different than the OEM single license key found on the COA sticker. This is a great idea for home built PCs and OEM, never hurts to do this.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/w/microsoft_os/3317.2-3-microsoft-windows-vista-official-iso-download-links-digital-river.aspx) to a Dell webpage containing download links and instructions for creating Windows Vista (with SP1) bootable DVDs.

Answer (score 3):

you can try contacting the manufacturer, sometimes they ask for a small fee to send a set of recovery dvds, some even do it for free.
I guess it depends how old the computer in question is

Comment: This is the most straightforward idea, but it has the disadvantage of being slow.  Most manufacturers won't provide an image, but mail a disc.