# How to re-image a store-bought Windows Vista 64-bit?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, installation, windows-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a product key finder for a PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/176306/is-there-a-product-key-finder-for-a-pc)
>   [How can an operating system be installed when the installation media is missing?](https://superuser.com/questions/204106/how-can-an-operating-system-be-installed-when-the-installation-media-is-missing)

OK, so I have a Windows Vista... more specifically this: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883103182 a Acer Aspire AX3200-U3600A Desktop.

I know, I know. Kill me.

Anyway, this computer did not come with a CD key if I recall correcty. I want to reimage it but wouldn't I need the installation CD?

Comment: Are you sure there's no key? Typically on a sticker on the side of the machine.

Comment: This is essentially a dup of http://superuser.com/questions/176306/is-there-a-product-key-finder-for-a-pc

Comment: This is not a dupe, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Acer has a recovery partition, you can [recover it by using Alt+F10](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/desktop/0000/Acer/AspireE360/AspireE360faq40.shtml) at the bios splash screen.

You can also [make your own Recovery Media](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/desktop/0000/Acer/AspireE360/AspireE360faq67.shtml)

[Your Support Page](http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=2&modelId=402)

Answer (score 1):

The previous question [How can an operating system be installed when the installation media is missing?](https://superuser.com/questions/204106/how-can-an-operating-system-be-installed-when-the-installation-media-is-missing) appears to only cover Windows 7.

Here's a [link](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/w/microsoft_os/3317.2-3-microsoft-windows-vista-official-iso-download-links-digital-river.aspx) on one of Dell's websites that describes a fairly involved process to create a bootable DVD for Windows Vista with SP1.  Check is out and advise if this works for you.

Comment: You may want to suggest an edit to the accepted answer to that question instead.

Comment: Thank you ... I will ... Do I do that by adding a comment to the accepted answer including the link?

Comment: Click on the **Edit** link below the post to edit it, placing the link and associated text in the most appropriate location in the post.  Your edit will be placed into a queue until it is reviewed; I will likely review the edit for you.

Comment: Edit approved with some minor changes.

Comment: Thank you, I have contacted Acer for a chance they give me new installation CD.